# login method is not recognised in xmpp

Tags: java, android, smack, asmack

I am trying to connect to openfire server with smack library in android. but getting error in login method.

```
public void performLogin(String username, String password) throws XMPPException {
        if (connection!=null && connection.isConnected()) {
            connection.login(username, password);
        }
    }
```

error is

```
The method login(String, String) from the type XMPPConnection refers to the missing type SaslException
```

what is the issue here?

Comment: Hard to tell if you don't tell us more about your environment, e.g. which Smack version do you use on Android?

Comment: smack_4_0_4 is in use and openfire is installed in windows

Comment: smack only..
this one.. http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/download-landing.jsp?file=smack/smack_4_0_4.zip

Comment: Try to follow my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100058/smack-4-1-openfire-sample-example/28405722#28405722

Answer (score 0):

Smack 4.0 does not work on Android, use [aSmack 4.0.](https://github.com/flowdalic/asmack)

Smack 4.1 will run on Android, but isn't released yet.

Comment: I tried the asmack example for android. but these starting statement itself not recognized by eclipse. I copied the jars into library and did all formalities.

ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration("192.168.0.1", 5222);
        connConfig.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
     connConfig.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);